# Hive Substring from complex subquery

Tags: sql, string, hive, hiveql, greenplum

As below substring is developed by Greenplum platform, we have to migrate similar operation to Hive supported. kindly help us.

```
select substring(a.dealer_msisdn from char_length(a.dealer_msisdn)-9) as dealer_msisdn
```

example of msisdn value with above query for greenplum

```
select substring('9970050916' from char_length('9970050916')-9) as dealer_msisdn
```

Please help me similar operation needs to migrate hive.

Comment: what it returns in greenplum?

Comment: same msisdn no : 9970050916 but hive throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hive substring function syntax is different:
`substr(string|binary A, int start, int len)`, len is optional parameter.

Try this:

```
select substr('9970050916', char_length('9970050916')-9)
```

---

Read [Hive UDFs manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf)